# How to write Spark XML writing with order by?

Tags: xml, scala, apache-spark, sql-order-by, apache-spark-xml

am trying to write xml file from my dataframe like below

```
 myDf.orderBy("name")
.repartition(1).write
.format("com.databricks.spark.xml)
.option("rootTag","colname")
.option("rowTag","colname2")
.save("filename")
```

This is writing a file but not following the order I specify. Every-time it gives different random order. How to get ordering proper in spark XML writing

Comment: Is the dataframe before you write it ordered ? You can check it doing ```myDf.orderBy("name").show()```

Comment: Yes that is also ordered properly. But still everytime final write is giving random order